# Integration of Oracle Wallet, JDBC and LDAP

Tags: jdbc, oracle11g

I currently have Oracle 11g and Java6 and can connect via JDBC thin client using Oracle Wallet to store the username and pasword keyed by Database ID, this id is defined in tnsnames.ora. We are required to change from tnsnames to a centrally managed LDAP server and am looking for help on how to set this up

Thanks

Comment: It looks like Wallet and ldap cannot be used together in JDBC because of the way the JDBC code decodes the supplied url

Answer (score 0):

JDBC and Oracle Wallet cannot integrate directly with LDAP.  You should look into another tool, like Cyber-Ark (http://www.cyber-ark.com/), which provides a Java API (and command line API) for retrieving credentials securely from a local or remote safe.  Then you can use Cyber-Ark to manage both your Safe and Database passwords and keep them in sync.